# C# access asp controls in WebService class

Tags: c#, web-services

I`m trying to access asp.net controls like label, PlaceHolder etc in my web service class. I have tried a few ways to do it but no luck.

This is my control in ASPX page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

My WebService class inherits my ASPX class

```
[WebMethod]
    public string buildFunctionParams(int one, string two)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "test";

        ph1.Controls.Add(txt);
        return "Build success";
    }
```

This gives an error object ref is not set to an instance of object. I understand I cannot access my asp controls outside the aspx class. Is there a way I can pass my controls to webservice?

Comment: Aren't the Webmethods supposed to be static ?

Comment: You can't do that, you are trying to combine Web over HTTP and SOAP over HTTP... Whats the point in doing that?

Comment: the ph1 is a placeholder. I want to add controls on JQuery call to my webmethod

Comment: I understand I have changed my function in another way. Cheers

Comment: You would rather make a postback call for that.

Comment: Thats how I changed my function